# Throw an exception when open a gradle application by Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm a newer to `gradle`,and when i open a `gradle` application with `idea`,Then it throw an error `Gradle 3.1 requires Java 7 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 6`.

My `gradle` info:

---

### Gradle 3.1

Build time:   2016-09-19 10:53:53 UTC

Revision:     13f38ba699afd86d7cdc4ed8fd7dd3960c0b1f97

Groovy:       2.4.7

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015

JVM:          1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23)

OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64

---

### idea

[image]

error

[image]

idea setting

file -> other settings -> default project setting

[image]

**EIDT**

Log

```
2016-10-30 14:25:06,941 [1651420]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at '/Users/famoss/Downloads/btrace-master/gradle' 

org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation '/Users/famoss/Downloads/gradle-3.1'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException: Gradle 3.1 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6.
```

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: @Makoto,I added the log to the content.

Comment: You might want to try older version of Gradle. I had the same problem with Gradle 3.1 at home. Now I'm at work and everything is working with Gradle 2.3.

The other difference is IntelliJ version: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4 at work, some older version at home. But I bet Gradle version makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the idea version to `2016.2.5` and the problem solved.

Comment: Yup, it helped :) Thx Baby.zhou

After fixing thos problem I had another weird error: 
" WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.<init>(Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/FileResolver;)"
If you have the same problem just check your shadow plugin version.
In build.gradle  look for something like this:

    plugins {
       id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4'
    ...

Upgrade it if it's < 1.2.4

Comment: Yup, it helped :) Thx Baby.zhou 

After fixing thos problem I had another weird error: 
`WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause:`
`org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.<init>‌`
`​(Lorg/gradle/api/int‌​ernal/file/FileResol‌​ver;) `

 If you have the same problem just check your shadow plugin version. In `build.gradle` look for something like this: 

`plugins { id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4' ... `

Upgrade it if it's < 1.2.4.

PS. Sorry for the formatting, I don't know how to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your local.properties file to see which version of java gradle is trying to reference. This file should be in the same directory as your gradle file.

Typically this file is automatically configured on project creation, but it depends on your intellij settings.